# ARC Not Release View Controller Variable

Tags: ios

I got the following variable in my view controller's @private section, sometimes ARC seam to release it where I want it to stay and not be collected.. How?

NSMutableArray* carPictures;

Thanks

Comment: There's not enough information to answer your question. Try declaring it as a `strong` property ie `@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *carPictures;` and then set the variable with `self.carPictures = [NSMutableArray array];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not enough information to answer your question. Try declaring it as a `strong` property ie

`@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray *carPictures;`

and then set the variable with

`self.carPictures = [NSMutableArray array];`